# To change the Opportunity owner under certain condition

Tags: process-builder

I have the below requirement,
For opportunities that are open, and where current owner if Web or Admin, to update the owner to the first agent that touch the opportunity, then to keep this agent as owner throughout , even if a second agent touch it.

I am trying to achieve it through PB, but if anyone suggest what would be my criteria and action ?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Could you please add more detail on how you handle new opportunities. Do use queues and assignment rules? And how the first owner can be changed in your process. I mean it's not clear why would you need to bother keeping the first as the owner; when you assign the owner to an opportunity it doesn't change when another agent views it provide you don't have any automated processes to change the owner.

Comment: Hi Eduard, When opp are created through Web, the owner is " Web" but then certain agents pick it up to do the further work and follow up on the Opp, and his bonus depends upon if he is able to convert it or not. So, as he already started working on the Opp, if a second agent touch it , it should not change the owner. The first agent would be the owner till the opp is won or lost. If i am clear ? All the opp with owner as web or admin, need to be picked by certain agents and henceafter they should be the owner. Thanks

Comment: But my need is, If its Web or admin, the first person modified the Opp, should be the opp owner, Can you plz suggest how to achieve this. Then may be on second step i can put a VR not to change. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Process Builder process to update the owner if the current owner is Web or Admin. You can also use trigger for this, but PB is enough.

[image]

Utilize formulas and System Variables to assign current user as the owner.
[image]

2. To prevent changing the first owner of an opportunity create a Validation rule  if it's not Web or Admin.

Comment: But my need is, If its Web or admin, the first person modified the Opp, should be the opp owner, Can you plz suggest how to achieve this. Then may be on second step i can put a VR not to change. thanks